# Narrowed Seekbar button on sliding in Android (with own thumb xml)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've got problem with Android SeekBar.

When I use standard thumb (blue) it's OK, but when I use own theme like scrubber_control.xml there is problem - button is narrowed.  I've tried setting minimal height, padding, adding height / width to scrubber_control item, but can't fix that strange issue.

[image]

## layout

```
<SeekBar
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/question_seekbar"
android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control"
/>
```

## scrubber_control.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_disabled_holo" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_focused_holo" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_normal_holo" />
</selector>
```

Comment: remove max height and min height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom shape xmls in drawables which define the height and width of thumb

that is used for all three shapes used in scrubber_control.xml

**For Example :**

**In drawable folder add these xmls**

**custom_scrubber_control_pressed_holo.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_pressed_holo"/>

</layer-list>
```

**custom_scrubber_control_focused_holo.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_focused_holo"/>

</layer-list>
```

**custom_scrubber_control_disabled_holo.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_disabled_holo"/>

</layer-list>
```

**custom_scrubber_control_normal_holo.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_normal_holo"/>

</layer-list>
```

After that you just need to change your selector like this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_enabled="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" />
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" />
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control_focused_holo" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control_normal_holo" />
 </selector>
```